# @Query annotation using like %?1%

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql, spring-data

I'd like to write a query like this

```
@Query("select p from Product p where p.name = ?1 or p.desc like %?1%")
```

but it gives me the exception

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: % near line 1,
```

I tried replacing % with '%' or concatenating the query string like this: "select ... like '%'" + "?1" + "'%'" but with no luck, please help me

Comment: Which version of Spring Data JPA are you using?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Spring Data JPA version 1.3.1 or later you need to do the following:

```
@Query("select p from Product p where p.name = :name or p.desc like %:name%")
public List<Product> searchByName(@Param("name") String name);
```

Check out [this](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-new-like-expressions-of-spring-data-jpa/) blog post for more details

Prior to Spring Data JPA 1.3.1, you could not use `%` in the @Query annotation, but instead you needed to add it in the argument itself

Comment: is this safe from sql injection?

Answer (score 2):

use the CONCAT as following:

```
@Query("select p from Product p where p.name = ?1 or p.desc like CONCAT('%',?1,'%') ")
```